# Get all calendars in Google Apps Scripts CalendarApp class

Tags: google-calendar-api, google-apps-script

So Google Apps Scripts allow you to `getCalendarByID`, `getCalendarsByName` and `getDefaultCalendar`, which works great when you need to target a specific calendar. However, I was wondering if there's a way for me to get **ALL** the Calendars that is associated with the account?

I've tried `getCalendarsByName()`, `getCalendarsByName('')` and `getCalendarsByName('*')`, none of which works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

have you tried `getAllCalendars()` ?   [Get all Calendars subscribed to by this user](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_calendarapp#getAllCalendars)

Comment: Wow that works! I didn't know this method was available, it wasn't shown on the Google Apps Script reference.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
function get_calendars() {
var calendars = CalendarApp.getAllCalendars();
for (var i = 0; i < calendars.length; i++) {
var calendar = calendars[i];
Logger.log(calendar.getName());
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks Tri. Serge's answer wasn't complete for a newbie like me. If I'm subscribed to say 35 calendars, getAllCalendars() will return "35". The rest of my code gets the actual names of those 35 calendars.